# Translate Unicode mathematical bold/italic characters to latin-1 in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

Unicode has separate characters for bold or italic characters, e.g. U+1D43B is an italic H. See https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=mathematical for list of these.

When a user copies a chemical formulae from an electronic textbook, they may actually be copying these characters instead of the Latin-1 characters, so instead of "H2O" they are copying "U+1D43B  U+2082 U+1D442". It *looks* like H2O when they paste it in the search form. But they'll get no results because it's not latin characters.

So, I need to translate these characters to Latin-1 characters in Perl.  The Text::Unidecode library doesn't seem to recognise these.

I tried using transliteration,

```perl
 y/\x{1d434}-\x{1d467}/A-Za-z/
```

but this doesn't seem to work at all.

Is there a way to use the translation operator on unicode character ranges? Or is there a library that will do this?

Comment: No, no, no. There are not special characters for bold and italics, and this is explicitly defined in Unicode principles. `MATHEMATICAL ITALIC H` has a specific semantics, and it should not be used for H2O. BTW you should check/google NFKC or NFKD (Unicode compatible normalization) which should covert this (and maybe also the subscript 2, etc) into *normal* characters.

Comment: I agree that it should not be used that way. But somebody else is, and this is affecting users.

Comment: [Unicode::Normalize](http://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::Normalize)

Comment: In any case, for searches, you should normalize the text (it is not the only surprise you may get). https://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode/Normalize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the transliteration operator does work. It was a matter of ensuring the variable was correctly encoded.

```perl
$str =~ y/\x{1d400}-\x{1d6a3}/A-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-zA-Za-z/r
  =~ y/\x{1d7ce}-\x{1d7ff}/0-90-90-90-90-9/r );
```

Seems to work.

However, `Unicode::Normalize::NDKD` works better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it does work.

```perl
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my $s = "\N{U+1D43B}\N{U+2082}\N{U+1D442}";
say sprintf "%vX", $s;
$s =~ y/\x{1d434}-\x{1d467}/A-Za-z/;
say sprintf "%1\$vX %1\$s", $s;
```

Output:

```
1D43B.2082.1D442
48.2082.4F H₂O
```

Perhaps you don't actually have the three-character string you describe? Perhaps you have the text encoded using UTF-8 instead?